# Spring Integration 2nd Aggregate and Release Strategy not working correct

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm trying to get a release strategy working correctly for file processing in directories.
After two splits for directories and files, we then aggregate and use a release strategy to release the first 25 files to be posted. The first 25 post correctly, though anything after that get's completely ignored and the integration completes without every releasing the last files.

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow QueueJamsPostJobsByFile() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(IntegrationNamesEnum.QUEUE_JAMS_POST_JOBS_BY_FILE.toString())
                .handle((p, h) -> {
                    try {
                        /* need to get all the files in this folder */
                        JsonObject obj = JsonParser.parseString(p.toString()).getAsJsonObject();
                        fileFilter = obj.get("fileFilter").getAsString();
                        return obj.get("dirName").getAsString();
                        
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        QUEUE_JAMS_POST_JOBS_BY_FILE.info("Exception Queueing File(s) to JAMS " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        responseBean = new EsbResponsePayloadBean();
                        responseBean.setReturnHttpStatusCode("500");
                        responseBean.setReturnPayload("Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        responseBean.setReturnStatusCode("-1");
                        responseBean.setReturnStatusDesc("Exception Queueing File(s) to JAMS " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(responseBean.getReturnPayload())
                                .setHeader("rtn_http_status_code", responseBean.getReturnHttpStatusCode())
                                .setHeader("rtn_status_code", responseBean.getReturnStatusCode())
                                .setHeader("x-error-message", "Exception Queueing File(s) to JAMS " + e.getLocalizedMessage())
                                .setHeader(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE,
                                        responseBean.getReturnHttpStatusCode())
                                .build();

                    }

                })
                .gateway(IntegrationNamesEnum.GET_SUBDIRECTORIES_INTGRTN.toString())
                /*split for each file. each one will gateway into jams submit integration independently*/
                .split()
                .handle((p, h) -> {
             
                  return MessageBuilder.withPayload(p)
                          .setHeader("x-esb-file-filter", fileFilter)
                          .setHeader("x-esb-directory-path", p.toString())
                          .build();  
                })
                .gateway(IntegrationNamesEnum.GET_FILES_INTGRTN.toString())
                .split()
                .filter(Message.class,
                        m -> m.getHeaders().get("x-error-message") == null
                                || m.getHeaders().get("x-error-message").toString().isEmpty(),
                        e -> e.discardChannel("discardChannel"))
                .handle((p, h) -> {
                    try {
                        String Directory=h.get("x-esb-directory-path").toString();
                        File f = new File(Directory+p.toString());
                        String file = f.getAbsolutePath();
                        f=null;
                        
                        return file;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        QUEUE_JAMS_POST_JOBS_BY_FILE.info("Exception creating JAMS Payload" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        responseBean = new EsbResponsePayloadBean();
                        responseBean.setReturnHttpStatusCode("500");
                        responseBean.setReturnPayload("Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        responseBean.setReturnStatusCode("-1");
                        responseBean.setReturnStatusDesc("Exception creating JAMS Payload " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(responseBean.getReturnPayload())
                                .setHeader("rtn_http_status_code", responseBean.getReturnHttpStatusCode())
                                .setHeader("rtn_status_code", responseBean.getReturnStatusCode())
                                .setHeader(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE,
                                        responseBean.getReturnHttpStatusCode())
                                .build();
                    }
                })
                //Release Strategy Here:
                .aggregate(a -> a.releaseStrategy(g -> g.size() > 25)
                        .expireTimeout(30000)
                        .groupTimeout(30000)
                        .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
                        .expireGroupsUponTimeout(true))
                .handle((p, h) -> {
                    
                    FileListMessageBean fileListMessageBean = new FileListMessageBean();
                    List<FileListMessageBean.FileName> filesList = new ArrayList<FileListMessageBean.FileName>();
                    
                    List<String> fileList = (List<String>) p;
                    
                    for(String fileName : fileList) {
                        FileListMessageBean.FileName payloadFile = fileListMessageBean.new FileName();
                        payloadFile.fileName = fileName;
                        
                        FileProperty fp = fileListMessageBean.new FileProperty();
                        fp.filePropertyName = "DirectoryToWritePayloads";
                        fp.filePropertyValue = FilenameUtils.getFullPath(fileName);
                        
                        List<FileListMessageBean.FileProperty> fileProps = new ArrayList<FileProperty>();
                        fileProps.add(fp);

                        payloadFile.fileProperties = fileProps;
                        
                        filesList.add(payloadFile);
                    }
                    
                    fileListMessageBean.setFiles(filesList);
                    
                    JAMSScheduleJobRequestPayload structureBean = new JAMSScheduleJobRequestPayload();
                    JAMSScheduleJobRequestPayload.Root structureBeanRoot = structureBean.new Root();
                    structureBeanRoot.setName("\\AlliantData\\Installs\\Prep\\Esb_Post_UID_File");
                    structureBeanRoot.setFolderName("POST API");
                    structureBeanRoot.setOverrideName("Esb_Post_UID_File");
                    
                    List<JAMSScheduleJobRequestPayload.Parameter> parameterList = new ArrayList<>();
                    JAMSScheduleJobRequestPayload.Parameter ESB_s_Payload = structureBean.new Parameter();
                    ESB_s_Payload.setParamName("ESB_s_Payload");
                    ESB_s_Payload.setParamValue(GsonUtil.gson.toJson(fileListMessageBean, FileListMessageBean.class));
                    parameterList.add(ESB_s_Payload);
                    JAMSScheduleJobRequestPayload.Parameter ESB_s_Topic_Header = structureBean.new Parameter();
                    ESB_s_Topic_Header.setParamName("ESB_s_Topic_Header");
                    ESB_s_Topic_Header.setParamValue(IntegrationNamesEnum.POST_UID2_API.toString());
                    parameterList.add(ESB_s_Topic_Header);
                    structureBeanRoot.setParameters(parameterList);
                    
                    String json = GsonUtil.gsonbuilder.disableHtmlEscaping().create().toJson(structureBeanRoot);
                    return json;

                })
                .handle((p, h) -> {
                    
                    QUEUE_JAMS_POST_JOBS_BY_FILE.info("Payload: ", p.toString());
                    return p;
                })
                .gateway(IntegrationNamesEnum.JAMS_SUBMIT_JOB_INTGRTN.getChannelName())
                /* aggregate the fileListMessageBean files */
                .aggregate()
                .handle((p, h) -> {
                    
                    QUEUE_JAMS_POST_JOBS_BY_FILE.info("Payload: ", p.toString());
                    return p;
                })
                .handle((p, h) -> {
                    QUEUE_JAMS_POST_JOBS_BY_FILE.info("Process Completed", h, Level.DEBUG);
                    return p;
                })
                .log(Level.DEBUG, m -> "**** Payload: " + m.getPayload())
                .log(Level.DEBUG, m -> "**** Headers: " + m.getHeaders())
                .logAndReply();
        }
```

I figure that the release strategy is incorrectly implemented?

I've tried multiple times to adjust the aggregate functions with no success:

```
.aggregate(a -> a.releaseStrategy(g -> g.size() > 25)
                        .expireTimeout(30000)
                        .groupTimeout(30000)
                        .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
                        .expireGroupsUponTimeout(true))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if this option helps you somehow to be set to `true`:

```
/**
 * @param expireGroupsUponCompletion the expireGroupsUponCompletion.
 * @return the aggregator spec.
 * @see AggregatingMessageHandler#setExpireGroupsUponCompletion(boolean)
 */
public AggregatorSpec expireGroupsUponCompletion(boolean expireGroupsUponCompletion) {
```

I also see that you have some error handling logic where you build a fresh `Message`, but at the same time you don't supply request message headers. Must not be the case because a `handle()` does that unconditionally, but still worth to try.

You might not wait though for that `.groupTimeout(30000)` in the request for that `IntegrationNamesEnum.QUEUE_JAMS_POST_JOBS_BY_FILE` channel.